# Same height for table-rows using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have N rows of content that user should match using drag and drop (user moves items on the right to the corresponding item on the left). Here is an example:

[image]

All blocks should have the same height - the height of the largest item. (In this example the larges item is on the left, #2). Is it possible to do using pure CSS? I can't use flexbox due to browser support. I have managed to implement this using JS, but I don't like that solution :)

Maybe someone could point me to the technique or a similar example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your table in a jsfiddle? I got a idea how to fix your problem! :-)

Comment: I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/px0udsjz/

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle example with your code!

Answer (score 1):

Try this jquery code it detects the biggest element and sets all of them to that height.

```
var height = 0;
$(".table").find(".table-cell").each(function() {
    height = Math.max(height, $(this).height());
});

$(".table").find(".table-cell").css("height", height);
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px0udsjz/2/) example.

You need jquery for this so make sure adding the jquery library to your code.

Comment: I have managed to do this using JS. The problem of JS solution is that when you resize a widnow or change the orientation - you have to recalculate again and again

Comment: You can give it like 200px width? and probally a media query wich makes the width smaller when its on a mobile phone/tablet?

Comment: Can't do them fixed according to the task, they should be fully responsive :(